# Wordpress Multisite, htaccess 301 redirect for permalink change

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

I´ve got a running Wordpress Multisite where I want to change the Permalinks and 301 redirect with htaccess.
Changing the permalinks in Wordpress isn´t a problem but all the Links that are around to my site would be broken so I want to fix this with 301.

I´m trying to redirect `https://subsite.example.com/blog/%postname%/` to `https://subsite.example.com/something-nice/%postname%/` where `blog` isn´t a real directory because of Wordpress.

I´ve tried the following but it doesn´t work:

```
# subsite Rewrite Rules

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite.example.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ ^/something-nice/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ ^/something-nice/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
> ------------------------|
> ```

Remove the `^` at the start of the *substitution* string.

You will need to clear your browser cache, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser (and possibly intermediary caches). Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. (That is assuming you put this rule at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file.)

This rule needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker). (If you put this rule at the end of the file then it won't do anything, since it won't be processed for such URLs.)